# Substitute calculated frame by selector input if checkbox checked Shiny

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny, conditional-statements, heatmap

Hi Everyone I'm still working on this issue :
a calculated average feeds into the axis of a heatmap. I want to override the calculation if the checkbox 'override' is checked.

I tried many things and nothing has worked. The score calculated is :

```
      project_gap_score<- reactive({
    project_gap_table_prep() %>%
      select(rank) %>%
      drop_na() %>%
      mutate(rank = as.numeric(str_extract(rank, '\\d{1}'))) %>%
      summarise(score = round(mean(rank)))%>%
      mutate(
        label = case_when(
          score == 1 ~ 'Low',
          score == 2 ~ 'Medium',
          score == 3 ~ 'Large',
          score == 4 ~ 'Very Large'))
```

so I created something similar to replace this in case if the checkbox was checked :

```
  project_gap_scoreover<- reactive({
    variable() %>%
      mutate(
        value = case_when(
          'Low' ~ score == 1,
           'Medium'~ score == 2,
           'Large'~ score == 3,
          'Very Large'~ score == 4))

  })
```

Meaning, if the person selected in the pickerselector "Medium" it's a score of 2 etc.
I figured that I may need a callback to get the checkbox input since it's not in the reactive event of the heatmap. That being said, I still can't figure out how to override that axis input. is my function misplaced or completely wrong?

```
  project_potential_heatmap_prep <- reactive({


    hold_gap_label <- project_gap_score()
    hold_intensity_label <- project_intensity_score()


    dat_out <- tibble(
      gap = rep(c(0, 1, 2, 3), 4),
      intensity = c(rep(0, 4), rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4), rep(3, 4)),
      dat = rep(1, 16),
      color = c('#FFC000', rep('#C6E0B4', 5), rep('#92D050', 2), '#C6E0B4', rep('#92D050', 2), '#00B050', rep('#92D050', 2), rep('#00B050', 2))
    )

    if (!is.na(project_intensity_score()$score) && !is.na(project_gap_score()$score)) {
      dat_out <- dat_out %>%
        mutate(dat = ifelse(gap == hold_gap_label$score - 1 & intensity == hold_intensity_label$score - 1, 99, dat))
    }
    if (!is.na(input$override) {
      project_gap_score <- project_gap_scoreover
    }

    dat_out
  })
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Comment: Can you please try to create a reproducible example regarding your issue? It's very hard to help based on some isolated code snippets.

Comment: got it, thanks, it might take me a little while but I'll post it asap. I also discovered that the code is not intuitive, even though the labels are 1, 2, 3, 4, the highlighted titles are the result of the intersection score which completely different.